# Get all the related data from WordPress DB

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql, wpdb, sql

I have 2 custom tables inside the DB WordPress is installed in, With `one-to-many` relation between both tables.

Here are the two tables:

```
                     posts table
_________________________________________________________________
| id | title | content | category_id | post_order  | post_active |                                        
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|_____________|
| 1  | test1 | testing |     1       |       0     |      1      |
| 2  | test2 | testing |     1       |       1     |      1      |
| 3  | test3 | testing |     2       |       2     |      0      |
| .  | ..... | ....... |     .       |       .     |      .      |
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|_____________|


       categories table
_____________________________________
| c_id | c_name | c_order | c_active |                                       
|______|________|_________|__________|
|   1  |  cat1  |    0    |    1     |
|   2  |  cat2  |    1    |    1     |      
|   3  |  cat3  |    2    |    0     |  
| .    | .....  | ....... |    .     |      
|______|________|_________|__________|
```

As you see each post has a category using both `category_id` column in `posts` table and `c_id` column in `categories` table.

I want to show all the data from `posts` table with the related category.

That's what I tried:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT b.c_name, a.id, TRIM(a.title) AS title, a.content
FROM posts a
INNER JOIN categories b ON a.category_id = b.c_id
WHERE a.post_active = '1' AND b.c_active = '1'
ORDER BY b.c_order, a.post_order", OBJECT_K );

print_r($results);
```

But I only get the first post in each active `category`:

```
Array
(
    [cat1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c_name] => cat1
            [id] => 1
            [title] => test1
            [content] => testing
        ) 

    [cat2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => cat2
            [id] => 3
            [title] => test3
            [content] => testing
        ) 
)
```

What's wrong and how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the constants OBJECT_K.

In the documentation you can read that this constant ensures that duplicate keys are discarded.

From the wordpress codex entry:

> Any of ARRAY_A | ARRAY_N | OBJECT | OBJECT_K constants. With one of the first three, return an array of rows indexed from 0 by SQL result row number. Each row is an associative array (column => value, ...), a numerically indexed array (0 => value, ...), or an object. ( ->column = value ), respectively. **With OBJECT_K, return an associative array of row objects keyed by the value of each row's first column's value. Duplicate keys are discarded.**

[Wordpress codex: get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)